# Why does DoCmd.transfertext acExport work and export using Current.Db.OpenRecordset not?

Tags: vba, ms-access, import, export-to-csv, recordset

I have created two methods to import text file to table in access and export from table to csv file.  The first method works fine. Imports and Exports without a glitch.  The 2nd method runs but the output file has no records.  For the 2nd method if I use a pause function for 5 seconds after the DoCmd.Transfer ac Importfixed the 2nd method produces the same results as the first method.  Why do I need the pause function?  Why does the first method not require a pause between import/export?  I'm currently using the 2nd method with the pause function which give me a more flexibility when I need to update the output. (code has been truncated)

First Method

```
Dim FileDate As String
FileDate = Format(WhatwasPriorBusinessDay(Date), "mmddyy")

DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "GLTransImportSpecs", "tbl_gltrans", "G:\Home\RiskMgtReports\AutoDatabase\GL Export Files\dv24gltrans " & FileDate & ".txt", False

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "GLTransExportSpecs", "qry_union_90_20", "G:\Home\RiskMgtReports\AutoDatabase\GL Export Files\Indirect_Auto_" & FileDate & ".csv", False
```

2nd Method

```
Dim db                          As DAO.Database
Dim rs                          As DAO.Recordset
Dim strQuery                    As String
Dim strDataSource               As String
Dim arGLStuff(5000, 13)         As String
Dim FileDate                    As String
Dim SumDebit                    As Currency
Dim SumCredit                   As Currency
Dim tempDate                    As String
Dim textExcelFile               As String

DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "GLTransImportSpecs", "tbl_gltrans", "G:\Home\RiskMgtReports\AutoDatabase\GL Export Files\dv24gltrans " & FileDate & ".txt", False
Pause (5)

Set db = CurrentDb

strQuery = "SELECT * From tbl_gltrans where debits > 0"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQuery)

glImportRecs = -1
SumDebits = 0
If rs.EOF Then
    Else
        With rs
            .MoveFirst
            While Not .EOF
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 0) = "135"
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 1) = !GLAccount
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 3) = "000"
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 4) = "90"
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 5) = Str(Abs(!Debits))
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 6) = "Tran Code " & !Transcode
        If !Level3 = "XX" Then
            arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 7) = "REGION MA" 'column H
        Else
            arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 7) = "REGION " & !Level3 'column H
        End If
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 8) = ""
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 9) = ""
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 10) = ""
        tempDate = Format(CDate(Format(!ProcessYMD, "00-00-00")), "mmddyy")
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 11) = tempDate
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 12) = ""
            .MoveNext
            Wend
        End With
End If

Set rs = Nothing

strQuery = "SELECT * From tbl_gltrans where credits < 0"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQuery)
SumCredits = 0
If rs.EOF Then
Else
    With rs
        .MoveFirst
        While Not .EOF
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 0) = "135"
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 1) = !GLAccount
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 3) = "000"
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 4) = "90"
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 5) = Str(Abs(!Credits))
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 6) = "Tran Code " & !Transcode
        If !Level3 = "XX" Then
            arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 7) = "REGION MA" 'column H
        Else
            arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 7) = "REGION " & !Level3 'column H
        End If
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 8) = ""
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 9) = ""
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 10) = ""
        tempDate = Format(CDate(Format(!ProcessYMD, "00-00-00")), "mmddyy")
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 11) = tempDate
        arGLStuff(glImportRecs, 12) = ""
       .MoveNext
       Wend
    End With
End If

Set rs = Nothing

Set db = Nothing
```

Next step exports this to csv file.

Comment: I would guess the import transaction is not finished when you open the recordset for step2, hence you are given the last committed version of the table- lacking the imported rows. Debug.print a row count on the recordset to ckeck.

Comment: Why would the table be available for DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim but not openrecordset.  Do you happen to know technically the difference?  Does DoCmd method see the records available sooner then openrecordset?

Comment: Sorry, I can only guess, once again, nothing to be found in my searchbubble. But how long does it take for the two transfertexts to complete? I assume that there is only one file handler at work and the second docmd has to wait for the first to finish. You can time the two docmds with Systemtime Millisecs [http://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/876984-format-system-time-milliseconds-vba] and see how long each takes. Just for clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: My first answer of Do..Loop with DCount to wait for the records to be inserted was was incorrect.  As it turns out, it was:

```
DBEngine.Idle dbRefreshCache
```

after the TransferText command which did the trick.

Comment: I added this to my code (peering into the text file to get the count) and still have the same results.  Do Until DCount("*", "tbl_gltrans") = textRcount
       Pause (1)
    Loop

Comment: It just sits?  Try DBEngine.Idle dbRefreshCache after you do the TransferText command.  Maybe the changes are being cached...

Comment: Excellent!  Happy you've got it sorted out.